# Azure website deployment: Can not load file or assembly report viewer VS 2013

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service

[image]

I am trying many solutions but can not solve my problem!
**I am using asp.net Web forms**

UPDATED:
also i tried to set property Set Copy Local to true BUT I Can not find this option! Only File name and Full path option!!
[image]

Please Help..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the referenced dll property Copy Local is set to true.
Also you seem to have a dll version problem, there is a mismatch between the dll version itself and the version referenced in the webconfig.
Try to remove/add back the reference.

Comment: thanks for your kind answer. But i need to know how to set property Copy Local to true?

Comment: Project->References click on the assembly, in the VS properties window change the Copy Local to true.

Comment: I am creating website using asp.net webforms

Answer (score 1):

You don't have required assembly in your project , you need to add reference to your project references and set property `CopyLocal` to true.
make sure to rebuild your project so new dll will be copied to bin folder and than deploy it again.

you'll find dlls `Windows\Assembly\GAC_MSIL` folder

Comment: thanks for your kind answer. but how set property CopyLocal to true?

Comment: select `dll` in solution explorer reference folder and than in property window set `copylocal` to true

Comment: Can not find this option! i have seen only file name and full path

Comment: @MohamedNasr You select the file in bin folder, you have to select it n `Project References`, there is `references` below  `propertises` in solution explorer, select dll and press `alt+enter` property window title will be `dll name .. Reference Propertises`

Comment: I am creating website using asp.net webforms

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all guys who trying to help me.

Problem solved after removing all DDls and add them again then deploy and publish

[image]